# Firing off event listeners and CSS classes in the same condition

Tags: javascript, css, events, conditional-statements

In the following code block in JS, I would like to hide/show a button depending on the validity of input fields in a form. When the .confirm button is clicked and the form is valid, I would like to fire off an event listener on the latter button to add a checkmark.

However, only the first two lines of code are firing off but the event listener is not. Any suggestions on how I could add/remove buttons and upon the same condition make the checkmark appear on the body?

```
if (form.checkValidity()) {
 document.querySelector(".formSubmit").classList.add("formSubmitShow");       
 document.querySelector(".confirm").classList.add("confirmHide");
 document.querySelector(".confirm").addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
         body.classList.add("checkmark");
        });
      } else {
        formElements.forEach((el) => {
          if (!el.checkValidity()) {
            el.classList.add("invalid");
          }
        });
      }
```

```
.checkmark {
  content: url(static/gifs/check.gif);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said

> When the .confirm button is clicked and the form is valid

so maybe you just need to restructure your code

The idea of having an event listener is not firing it when it's executed in code, but when the user make the event(which is something not known as the time of writing code & that's why it's made as a `listener`)

```js
document.querySelector(".confirm").addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  if (form.checkValidity()) {
    document.querySelector(".formSubmit").classList.add("formSubmitShow");
    document.querySelector(".confirm").classList.add("confirmHide");

    body.classList.add("checkmark");


  } else {
    formElements.forEach((el) => {
      if (!el.checkValidity()) {
        el.classList.add("invalid");
      }
    });
  }

});
```

I hope restructuring will help :D

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I would like to have the event fire off only when the form is valid and the .formSubmit has replaced the .confirm button. That is why I placed it after adding the CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the event does fire, the problem is you have misused the *content* css property.
Check the following link from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp). The content css property is meant to be used with the ::before and ::after pseudo elements. There is a example showing how it should be used: https://jsfiddle.net/vno85egh/.

```
.checkmark::after {
   content: url(path/to/asset);
}
```

Although in your case it seems to me you can simply set the body inner html:

```
document.body.innerHtml = "<img src=...>"
```

Hope this was somewhat helpful :).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I realised I was using it wrong after a while, but even when trying to set it as a background-image it wouldn't fire. I think it's a JS problem in this case and how I've structured the code around the event listener somehow.

Comment: @MéganeLondoño I guess you managed to solve the problem on your own... If you've found a desirable answer, may I suggest posting it on your free time? Have a nice day.